# How to create drawable folders in Android project?

Tags: android

In My Android app, I want to support different background size images for different screen sizes for phone's and tablet's.
I read about adding different size images in the following folders. But, I don't have these folders in my android project. I have only res/drawable and res/layout folder. How Can i get the multi screen folder created ?

```
drawable-xhdpi/
drawable-hdpi/
drawable-mdpi/
drawable-ldpi/
```

Comment: those are simply directories. You can use the ide or the shell. imo you can drop ldpi support

Comment: I am not getting your statement, could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just open the project using the file explorer of your computer (Files in Ubunutu, Finder in MacOS, Explorer in Windows) and manually create the folders.

In Android Studio the third icon on the top right corner is to synchronize the files from the computer with the project.

Also Android Studio have different ways of seeing the project that might be hiding empty folders. To see all of just like if it was on the computer file explorer, click on the right-hand side of top bar of the "Project window" (it's a drop down menu) and select the option `Project`